# Want to get output by passing multiple parameters in one go in Postgres function

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function

```
 dps.ds_parts_countertickets_open(locationid)
```

We access function by passing locationid as parameter, for eg: To get output for locationid=1 we will write,

```
select * 
from dps.ds_parts_countertickets_open(1).
```

Now I want to get data for 2 locationids simultaneously/in one output. for eg: To get output for locationid=1 and locationid=2 in one go. How do I do this?

Comment: You can use a UNION or change your function to accept a list of IDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a lateral join:

```
select * 
from (values (1), (2)) v(id) cross join lateral
     dps.ds_parts_countertickets_open(v.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is a [variadic function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS) that can accept a variable number of arguments. These are accessible in a PostgreSQL array in the function body.

The alternative is of course to have the function accept an array as argument.

Use whatever is more convenient for your case.